# Scaling a SurfaceView being used for Camera Previw

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I'm trying to build an app that shows a preview from the camera, but only shows it in about 1/4 of the screen.  I limited my SurfaceView to just that quarter, but my tests show that I'm not getting the full camera preview.

Is there a way to scale this and crop it to my specifications?